# What is the flute music for when in the frontier?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I often run around in the frontier and at seemingly random spots I hear a native american flute play. Often I look around to try to see if there is something around me to look for but I don't see anything. What is this flute-toot for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the flute is played there is some unusual animal event happening near you. Examples I have seen so far;

- Two deer bucks fighting
- A wolf pack
- A bear with cubs
- A deer with children

Sometimes it can be difficult to see, and sometimes you may have scared off the animal that caused the alert. But it's happened enough times for me to be pretty certain this is it.

A sidenote; I think I heard a different flute note once and just after I was attacked by a wolfpack. Could be that it was signalling danger?

Comment: Verified. Thank you. I guess I should stop running all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider your approach when in unknown territory. Though the alert song is very useful, you can never know what will happen, and I am certain that you would not want to desynchronize if you are in an important mission.